# Changing gallery code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I've made my own wordpress theme, and used a plugin for photo gallery. 
Now I am getting something like this:

```
<dl class='gallery-item'>
<dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
  <a href="http://*****.com/gallery/img_2233/">
    <img class="attachment-thumbnail" height="150" width="150" alt="IMG_2233" src="http://*****.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_2233-150x150.jpg" ...>
```

Can I change this code without any plugin? If so, where? I would like to use width and height in percent.

I would need the following result:

```
<dl class='gallery-item'>
<dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
  <a href="http://*****.com/gallery/img_2233/">
    <img class="attachment-thumbnail" height="60%" width="60%" alt="IMG_2233" src="http://*****.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_2233-150x150.jpg" ...>
```

Any suggestion where to change the gallery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css, you can override the attachment-thumbnail class.

Add this to the style.css or else via custom css.

```
.attachment-thumbnail {
height: 60% !important;
width: 60% !important;
}
```

Or else you can search for that term "attachment-thumbnail" and replace the existing height and width settings.